# Internet Explorer 9 in Internet Explorer 7 crashes while changing property in inspector

Tags: internet-explorer, crash, internet-explorer-7

My setup is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1 64-bit machine.

As a developer, I need to work with the F12 console of Internet Explorer to test modifications to the CSS to fit the Internet Explorer rendering engine.

My problem occurred five times in the past 12 hours: whenever I put IE into *IE7 compatibility view mode* and than change a property on an element, it crashes my entire computer.

It's getting very frustrating. I know that the ultimate answer to this question is to stop supporting Internet Explorer 7, but that's not currently an option (8.48% of usage via http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php).

How can I stop IE crashing in this way?

**Note:** I don't get this problem when using the inspector of Internet Explorer 9 or *IE8 compatibility mode*.